# ¿Cómo convertir consulta Linq To Sql en Asíncrona?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que esta consulta se ejecute de forma asíncrona?

Consulta:

```
var query = db.ShoppingProducts
                .Include(c => c.ShoppingCart)
                .Include(c => c.ShoppingCart.CmsUser)
                .Include(c => c.ShoppingCart.Country1)
                .Where( p => p.ItemStatus == (byte)ShoppingCartStatus.BOUGHT
                && p.ShoppingCart.ShoppingStatus == (byte)ShoppingCartStatus.BOUGHT
                && p.ShoppingCart.ResponsePaymentDate.HasValue
                && DateTime.Compare(p.ShoppingCart.ResponsePaymentDate.Value, filterModel.StartDate) >= 0
                && DateTime.Compare(p.ShoppingCart.ResponsePaymentDate.Value, filterModel.EndDate) < 0);
```

Comment: Que version de EF estas utilizando?

Comment: EF Core ... Einer